# How to get width of a Div or table in Pixels?

Tags: php, html

The main reason of this question is because I need the Width of a DIV element which holds an image, but the resize script (timtumb) only accepts pixel size and not % (will be great). for example :

```
 timthumb.php?src=castle1.jpg&h=230&w=640
```

If I set the width 640 I will have the image size to be displayed on PC will be Ok, but this same page will need to be shown on tablet or cellphone and the width on these devices are narrow, for example 480px, so  the DIV can be adjusted to 480px, but the scrip line need to change to:

```
 timthumb.php?src=castle1.jpg&h=125&w=480
```

this script only accepts numbers and not % or px 
I can do a multiple line script and hide some of these DIV's with CSS as responsive, but I want to enhance this code script :) if it possible, if not I will do a responsive patch.

Answer (score 1):

You can get div width px with javascript, and send it to php (via ajax for eg.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divWidth = document.getElementById("mydiv").clientWidth; 
</script>
```

Comment: :D and how can I echo the var divWidth, I got a blank line, of course I want to try this code.

Comment: this is javascript, you put in html inside <script> tags, not in php. You can't handle HTML with PHP (like image div) because PHP is server-side, PHP can only print (eg. echo "<img../>") but can't handle. Also, you should study more about it, and adam gave a good advice that doing your approach for responsive images is not the best way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801328/how-to-get-width-of-a-div-or-table-in-pixels/19801388?noredirect=1#comment29438668_19801468

Comment: I know how java scripts need to be tagged, and also some PHP and html since I'm handling forms in HTML and echoing inside PHP as variable; of course I will study more because I don´t know a lot how to pass information from one programming language to another.. :) thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You don't know... yet! The data communication from client-side to server-side (and vice-versa) is heavy used in many web applications, and it's called AJAX, search for it. Here's a starting guide: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div><img src="timthumb.php?src=castle1.jpg&h=230&w=640" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;" ></div>
```

Your image should "fit" automaticly to width of your parent div

Comment: This is not a reply for his question, also, this will only stretch the image, that could loss image quality or performance (if image size is bigger than displayed)

Comment: Yes i know, i`m giving alternative solution for his problem. It will only scale down image (max-width)

Comment: Change url of images via javascript for smaller images is pointless because request for biger images will be already send so you double number of requests. He would have to use some lazyloading technic to dynamicly calculate image size for current browser size, handle browser resize events etc.

Comment: Yes, using the style="width:100%;max-width:640px;" inside the code helps to get responsive the timthumb script. I will no get blurry images due I'm only scaling dowm and the images and are being cropped to 230x640 as maximum size.